# Add login feature and show specific content to users on WordPress Website

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, password-protection

I have a WordPress website that I use to introduce our Wedding company. I want to add the functionality that I can create/generate login credentials for each of my client. And when I give them the credentials and a url, they can login on that url using those credentials which can redirect them to a custom made page that displays only their photos/videos as a gallery.

Can you suggest how I can add this function to my site? Are there some plugins that can help me achieve this in free?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into buddypress area for an MVP. At least you get decent profiles out of the box and can build some logic around private pages / communities there. Of course, it's totally possible to do with any membership plugin too, but they all are too bloated for my taste. Better try it with BuddyPress and then develop from scratch with the logic you want.